# Script to cut vid into clips based on audio peak?

Tags: audio, script

I have a video that contains screams at various points. Is there a way to (via script) cut the screams out based on audio attributes then merge all clips into one supercut of just screams?

Comment: It did sound like the same question, but I didn't see a solution there.

Comment: Welcome! Can you give some more details about what you are looking for? When you say script, do you mean Linux shell, Windows command/power shell, something that runs in Premiere, or something else entirely? Is the audio clipping or just loud? Are you trying to hit a target loudness?

Comment: When I say peak, I just mean loudest points of audio. I assumed it would need to be a script to accomplish this, but any means of accomplishing it would be fine.

Comment: I found a YouTube video that explains exactly what I'm trying to do and it works very well. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wtmZnBpaRpI